# Navigate not working in react router dom. It is not redirecting me to the route I want

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Navbar.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
export default class Navbar extends Component {
    fetchQuery = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        const searchText = formData.get('search');
        console.log(searchText)
        this.props.setQuery(searchText);
        <Navigate to="/keyword" replace={true}/>
    }
    render() {
        return (
            // <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style={{ backgroundColor: "#35374B" }} data-bs-theme="dark">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style={{ backgroundColor: "#820300" }} data-bs-theme="dark">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <img src="favicon-32x32.png" alt="Logo" width="30" height="24" className="d-inline-block align-text-top " />
                    <Link className="mx-2 navbar-brand" to="/">KhabarDaar</Link>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/business">Business</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">Entertainment</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/health">Health</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/science">Science</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">Sports</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">Technology</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/random">Random</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                            </li>
                            {/* <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                            </li> */}
                            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                                <Link className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" to="/" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Country
                                </Link>
                                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">India</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">USA</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">China</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">Russia</Link></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            {/* <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</Link>
                            </li> */}
                        </ul>
                        <form onSubmit={this.fetchQuery} className="d-flex" role="search">
                            <input name="search" className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js file

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import News from './Components/News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom"

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      country: "in",
      query: ""
    }
  }
  setQuery = (q) => {
    this.setState({ query: q })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <Navbar setQuery={this.setQuery} />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<News key="general" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="general"></News>} />
            <Route path="/business" element={<News key="business" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="business"></News>} />
            <Route path="/entertainment" element={<News key="entertainment" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="entertainment"></News>} />
            <Route path="/health" element={<News key="health" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="health"></News>} />
            <Route path="/science" element={<News key="science" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="science"></News>} />
            <Route path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="sports"></News>} />
            <Route path="/technology" element={<News key="technology" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} category="technology"></News>} />
            <Route path="/keyword" element={<News key="technology" pageSize={9} country={this.state.country} q={this.state.query}></News>} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

It is not redirecting me to /keyword route. I don't know what is the exact issue here. I have refered the react-router-dom documentation too, still got no clue. My code is exactly as specified in documentation.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate
I new this because whenever It is redirecting to some new route my url bar shows that route but here it is not happening. However the fetchQuery() function is being surely called

Comment: Class-based react components in 2024?!

Answer (score -1):

I see that you are calling `fetchQuery` and then using `Navigate` component. This is an incorrect way of navigating on an event. You could have used `Navigate` on conditional render. However, if you are navigating on some event, you need to use a hook called `useNavigate()` as follows -

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/keyword");
```

Reference - https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: I am using Class based components. How I can use "useNavigate" hook here

Comment: You need to do some research instead of just asking for readymade solution. There can be several options that you can use - 1. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect 2. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/